# Критическая ошибка при переносе строки

Tags: android, java

Приветствую всех, возник может глупый вопрос.

Окрываю форму ввода - через:

```
View.VISIBLE
```

Далее ввожу текст в EditText - проверяю поля на пустоту через isEmpty.
Далее отправляется данные на сервер, уходят отлично - при условии, если не было переноса текста, если нажать на перенос текста, то вываливается fatal error.

Может кто сталкивался с таким?

UPD 19/02/12.
Набрасал на ночь глядя класс с методом httpGet:

```
    package meo.app.pigeon;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnRoutePNames;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class getPost {

    public String API_URL = "http://tjuryakin.ru/pigeon/api.php";
    public String DATA = "";
    public String RESULT_DB_POST = "";

    public String dbPost(String DATA) {
        String proxyHost = android.net.Proxy.getDefaultHost();

        int proxyPort = android.net.Proxy.getDefaultPort();

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        if (proxyPort > 0)

        {

          HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort);

          httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);

        }

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(API_URL + "?" + DATA);

        try {

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

               if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
               {
                   RESULT_DB_POST = "access";
               } 
               else 
               {
                   RESULT_DB_POST = "error";
               }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            RESULT_DB_POST = e.toString();
        }

        return RESULT_DB_POST;
    }

     public static final String md5(final String s) {
            try {
                // Create MD5 Hash
                MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest
                        .getInstance("MD5");
                digest.update(s.getBytes());
                byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

                // Create Hex String
                StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
                for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
                    String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
                    while (h.length() < 2)
                        h = "0" + h;
                    hexString.append(h);
                }
                return hexString.toString();

            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "";
        }

}
```

Comment: какая ещё фатал эррор? стэктрэйс в студию

Comment: Может быть, из-за разницы в `\r\n` и `\n` сломался парсер? Серверная часть покрыта тестами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index
```

так? Надо экранировать DATA. [см. Разрешенные символы в частях URL](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html)

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(API_URL + "?"+ URLEncoder.encode(DATA,"UTF-8"));
```